# Google Play API to fetch ratings and installations

Tags: android, google-play

Google Play developer console provides an [API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api) to manage app publishing.
But, is there an API to fetch the number of installations and the ratings?
We need to automate fetching of those data with some script we could run regularly without having to manually log on to the console to fetch the data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The app reports in Google Play Console's "Download Reports" section are sent to Google Cloud Storage automatically. The bucketId of the cloud storage they are sent to is displayed on that Developer console page.

Then it is possible to download the CSV reports either using:

- gsutils python tool
- API for several languages

As described in https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870

Answer (score -1):

I have used [AppMonsta](https://appmonsta.com/). They have pretty much everything you need when it comes to app store statistics, and the APIs are well [documented](https://appmonsta.com/dashboard/api-documentation/).

I have tried other platforms that offer the same service but IMO they offer the best API, I have tried it on an Android app. I can't remember the free tier but it was generous enough for my use case that I don't have to pay for premium.